# Can someone identify this brown spider in California

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Spider found on transit case from California. Approx 1 1/2 inches leg span. Is it poisionus?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks a lot like a *Kukulcania hibernalis*, or southern house spider. This one appears to be a female and if it were to bite you then it would be painful, but not dangerous. These spiders typically keep to themselves so unless you find one hanging in a really bad place it's better just to leave them alone.

For further information you can look here:

https://spiderid.com/spider/filistatidae/kukulcania/hibernalis/

Comment: Joseph, once again please provide support for your answer. We as kthat all answers (especially those regarding species ID) be supported by reputable sources that are cited or linked. Otherwise, we're no better than Yahoo Answers :p. I'm sure you know your spiders, but without outside evidence, your post appears no more than a comment. Please see our [help page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for additional notes regarding writing good answers on our site. Adding citations/sources will surely garner you additional upvotes as well. Thanks!